# 3 DIV's in a row, Can't keep text in the div

Tags: css, html, xhtml

I was able to get three div's in a row, no sweat.  Where the problem lies when the site is done some pages have text in the center column, however when i start typing the text spills over into the other divs..... The text doesn't wrap (stay in that div)

I'm sure I am probably missing one little dumb thing but any help would be greatly appreciated!

I uploaded a test of it for you guys to see:
http://graves-incorporated.com/test_sites/solera_new/test3col.html

and with the text spilling onto the next div:
http://graves-incorporated.com/test_sites/solera_new/test3col_2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you worry about nothing. Words like

```
Stufffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

are not found in many languages. You will see if you put normal language in your div, the text will not overflow at all

Comment: Oh wow, thanks, I thought you were joking at first but this actually worked!

Answer (score 2):

You could always use CSS's `word-wrap` [CSS Word-Wrap example](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap).

Or PHP's `wordwrap()` function [PHP Word-Wrap example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php).

There are various ways you can approach it, but that should set you off in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

I Think you must use  a proper language then it will not go out of Div's Width , Becase your DIV is already in a Fixed Width.Just use another the good words instead of stuuuuuuuuuuuufffffffff. It will work fine then :).

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea that could effect it!

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden` will help prevent it from breaking the layout, although some content may be hidden. I would suggest `word-break: break-all`, but that has a tendancy to break words unnecesarily.